# ngx-bootstrap datepicker loads incorrect date with dateInputFormat DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap datepicker v2.0.2. The BsDatepickerConfig is something like this

customer-detail.component.ts

```
bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.bsConfig = {
        containerClass: "theme-dark-blue",
        dateInputFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY"
    };
}
```

customer-detail.component.html

```
<label for="birthday" class="required">Birth date</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" bsDatepicker #dpDOB="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" formControlName="birthDate" placeholder="Birth date">
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="dpDOB.show()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
</div>
```

When loading a customer's DOB from a FormControl value, for example, the value is "1984-07-26T17:00:00+00:00", the client time zone is UTC/GMT +7. So my expected value is "27-07-1984" in the textbox and in the datepicker.

But it shows **"19-07-2026"** both in textbox and datepicker.

[image]

When I try to add value="{{personalInformation.controls.birthDate.value | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}"

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" bsDatepicker #dpDOB="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" formControlName="birthDate" placeholder="Birth date" value="{{personalInformation.controls.birthDate.value | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}">
```

The input textbox can show correct value but the datepicker still shows incorrect value as below.

[image]

I think this is a bug of ngx-bootstrap datepicker. Do you know a workaround for this issue?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Kevin

Comment: I also having same issue, it seems ngx-bootstrap showing maximum allowed date if there is invalid date.